# sql add columns in group dynamically

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, postgres-14

It is necessary to build a summary table based on data about the customer and their payments, where the columns will be the sequential number of the contract (`contact_number`) and the year (`year`) grouped by `gender`. The main condition is that `contact_number` and `year` should be dynamically generated.

Test data:

```
CREATE TABLE loans
(
    loan_id int,
    client_id int,
    loan_date date
);

CREATE TABLE clients
(
    client_id int,
    client_name varchar(20),
    gender varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO CLIENTS
VALUES (1, arnold, 'male'),
       (2, lilly, 'female'),
       (3, betty, 'female'),
       (4, tom, 'male'),
       (5, jim, 'male');

INSERT INTO loans
VALUES (1, 1, '20220522'),
       (2, 2, '20220522'),
       (3, 3, '20220525'),
       (4, 4, '20220525'),
       (5, 1, '20220527'),
       (6, 2, '20220527'),
       (7, 3, '20220601'),
       (8, 1, '20220603'),
       (9, 2, '20220603'),
       (10, 1, '20220603');
```

Formation of columns can be done using the `case when` construct, but this option is not suitable due to the need to constantly add new lines in the query when adding data.

My code:

```
    with cte as 
    (
        select 
            l.client_id,
            loan_date,
            extract(year from loan_date) as year,
            client_name,
            gender,
            row_number() over (partition by l.client_id order by loan_date asc) as serial_number_contact
        from 
            loans l
        inner join 
            client c on l.client_id = c.client_id
    )

select 
    gender
    , year
    , contract_number
    , count(*)
from cte
group by gender, year, contract_number
order by year, contract_number
```

expected Output :

| sex | 1 contract, 2022 | 2 contract, 2022 | 3 contract, 2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| male | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| female | 4 | 1 | 1 |

RDMBS - postgres

Comment: I would transpose columns into rows, and rows into columns, and find some tool that can convert this to the desired output.

Comment: You are probably approaching this problem like it is Excel which is wrong.